# USB Boot in HP Laptops

Tags: boot

My HP R007tX came with windows 8.1 pre-installed.

I want to remove it and install Ubuntu. I tried PendriveLinux to boot from USB but it didn't work. In fact, I can't boot from USB at all.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

Its the UEFI boot thats locking everything that is not signed specially for UEFI, try removing that option in the bios.
It should now acknowledge uour USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2) If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
3) Did you select the media check before trying to install?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4) Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.

Try using another disk burner program, "Startup Disk Creator" in Ubuntu, unetbootin
in windows.
For UEFI machines that won't boot from USB or USB UEFI, try turning off secure boot
(NOT changing out of UEFI mode to legacy mode, that's not necessary).